# Display Today's date outside the loop?

Tags: theme-development, themes, date, translation, localization

Is there any way to display the Today's date outside any loop/post using WordPress date/time function instead of using the PHP `date()` function?
I'm using the PHP `date()` function but it does not translate the date (month/day names) in the local languages, so it is not possible to translate it without changing the PHP code and setting the locale etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date_i18n()` from `wp-includes/functions.php`.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp.
 *
 * If the locale specifies the locale month and weekday, then the locale will
 * take over the format for the date. If it isn't, then the date format string
 * will be used instead.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $dateformatstring Format to display the date.
 * @param int $unixtimestamp Optional. Unix timestamp.
 * @param bool $gmt Optional, default is false. Whether to convert to GMT for time.
 * @return string The date, translated if locale specifies it.
 */
function date_i18n( $dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp = false, $gmt = false )
```